# dropzone unexpected formdata content

Tags: dropzone.js

I am trying to configure dropzone so that I can upload 2 files in a single request, using [ngx-dropzone-wrapper](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper).

```
private config: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 2,
    maxFiles: 2,
    maxFilesize: 500,
    url: environment.apiEndpoint + '/the/endpoint',
    acceptedFiles: 'image/jpeg',
    resizeWidth: 500,
    resizeMethod: 'contain',
    resizeQuality: 1.0,
    timeout: 30000,
    addRemoveLinks: true
};

// This allows me to access dropzone API
get dropzone() {
    return this.dropzonComponentRef.directiveRef.dropzone();
}
```

I am triggering the upload when the second file is dropped :

```
onFileAdded(file: File) {
    if (this.dropzone.files.length === this.config.maxFiles) {
      // All files have been dropped we can submit
      this.dropzone.processQueue();
    }
}
```

This callback is called two times as expected.

If I just do this, my files are not added to the formdata. I don't know if it is normal, but I could add them manually in another callback :

```
onSendingMultiple(args: any) {
    const formData = args[2];

    // We are not using the file array returned in args[0]
    // because in contains only one file for some reason
    const files = this.dropzone.files;
    formData.append('firstPic', files[0], 'firstPic.jpg');
    formData.append('secondPic', files[1], 'secondPic.jpg');
  }
```

This adds properly the files to the formdata, but there is also a third item in the formdata, that I would like to get rid of. I don't know where it comes from.

[image]

I checked the formdata content in the onSendingMultiple() callback, and this item is not part of the formdata by this time.

How can I get rid of it ? Or better, how can I avoid it to be generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was no need to add the files to the formdata by myself.

I noticed that calling :

```
this.dropzone.processQueue();
```

inside **onFileAdded()** callback will discard the last file of the formdata (that's why I ended up adding the files to the formdata myself).

I am now calling this from **onMaxFilesReached()** callback and my files are properly added to the formdata.